# How to move the image to bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

how do I make so that my image is on the bottom on any screen size and I also want my  to be under the feet of the human so that you must scroll down to see the

now it is like this
[image]
and I want it to be like this on all sreen size heights
[image]

my code to the project so far. I don't mind if i need to use some other language too.

```css
.navigation,
.activeBtn {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2vh;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.activeBtn {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.Lgo {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -70px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.seperationLine {
    border: none;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

nav {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 800px;
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    /* for demonstrating purposes */
}

.footerText {
    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 192);
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <a href="theCompany.html" class="activeBtn" class="navigation">The company</a>
        <a href="services.html" class="navigation">Services</a>
        <a href="referenceProjects.html" class="navigation">Reference project</a>
        <a href="background.html" class="navigation">Our background</a>
        <a href="contactForm.html" class="navigation">Contact us</a>
    </nav>
    <a href="theCompany.html" class="lgoLink">
        <img class="Lgo" src="../images/sapsamaLogo.jpeg" alt="Logo">
    </a>
    <hr class="seperationLine">
</header>
<div class="information">
    <img src="../images/hans.png" class="hansTransparent" alt="hans">
</div>
<footer>
    <p class="footerText">
        &copy; Tim Fredriksson 2020
    </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Try adding position: fixed; bottom: 10;  to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instead of a test picture (with a dove) you indicate your picture, you will get the desired result. First, you had to wrap everything in `main` div (that's right). Next, set the `height: calc (100vh - 128px)` for the `information` class, where `128px` is the height of the `header`. And for the picture set `margin-top: auto`. Was it necessary?

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue; /* for demonstrating purposes */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header {

}

.navigation, .activeBtn {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 2vh;
margin-left: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.activeBtn {
background-color: #e0e0e0;
padding: 15px;
border-radius: 25px;
}

.Lgo {
float: right;
clear: right;
height: auto;
margin-top: -70px;
width: 300px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.seperationLine {
border: none;
height: 1px;
margin-top: 50px;
background-color: black;
}

nav {
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 50px;
width: 800px;
}

.information {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 128px);
}

.information img {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: auto;

}

footer {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.footerText {
background-color: rgb(24, 24, 192);
color: white;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="main">
<header>
    <nav>
        <a href="theCompany.html" class="activeBtn" class="navigation">The company</a>
        <a href="services.html" class="navigation">Services</a>
        <a href="referenceProjects.html" class="navigation">Reference project</a>
        <a href="background.html" class="navigation">Our background</a>
        <a href="contactForm.html" class="navigation">Contact us</a>
    </nav>
    <a href="theCompany.html" class="lgoLink">
    <img class="Lgo" src="../images/sapsamaLogo.jpeg" alt="Logo">
    </a>
    <hr class="seperationLine">
</header>
<div class="information">
    <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/450/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg" class="hansTransparent" alt="hans">
</div>
<footer>
    <p class="footerText">
        &copy; Tim Fredriksson 2020
    </p>
</footer>
</div>
<body>
```